# SQL query to return "most nominated" from range of years, as list (with new columns)

Tags: mysql

I have a table (Nominated) that looks like:

```
Year  Category      Artist-Name                Title          Album
1980  AlbumOfYear   Michael Jackson            Thriller       Thriller
1980  ...           ...
1981  ...           ...
1982  ...           ...
```

I'm trying to develop a query that will return the most nominated Artist-Name from a range of years that the user will input, then return a list in descending order. Is something like this possible? (creating a new column for nominations and rank from a query)

something like

```
Rank   Artist              Nominations
1      Michael Jackson     3
2      Billy Joel          2
```

Comment: Yes. Perfectly feasible - although you wouldn't normally store data that can be so easily calculated 'on'the-fly' (although you might make a VIEW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @fromyear = 1980;
SET @toyear = 1992;


SET @rank = 0;


SELECT 
@rank:=@rank+1 as rank, 
noms.artist, 
noms.nominations
FROM
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as nominations, `Artist-Name` as artist 
    FROM `Nominations`
    WHERE `Year` BETWEEN @fromyear AND @toyear
    GROUP BY `Artist-Name`
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    ) as noms;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` this way:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 as rank, Artist-Name as Artist, count(*) as Nominations
WHERE Year = 1980
GROUP BY Artist-Name
ORDER BY Nominations DESC
```

Comment: OK this is almost perfect, but when i query "SET @rank=0; 
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 as rank, Name as Artist, count(Album) as Nominations 
FROM Nominated
WHERE Year BETWEEN 1980 AND 1984
GROUP BY Artist ORDER BY Nominations DESC"  I get nominations in order, but the ranks don't descend from 1 to N. They're random. The 1st row is 1, 2nd row is 17, 3rd row is 66, etc.  Thanks

Comment: The ranking gets messed up when using group by. You need to use a subquery which spits out the info in the right order, and then the ranking has to be applied to that result. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for oracle.

```
select rank() over(order by nominations desc),artist,nominations from   
(select artist,count(nominations) nominations from nominations where year between :loweryear and :higheryear group by artist);
```

Comment: The question was tagged "mysql".